# How to change the vimeo deafult skin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo-player, dailymotion-api

I need to know a way to change the vimeo player skin. I had done a bit of Google research and i came to know that it is not possible to change the vimeo skin as they do not allow it, the only thing we can do is that we can customize their controls.

Actually i have some videos from YouTube,Vimeo and Dailymotion embedded in my website, i need to have a common player for all those videos.

I know how to change the default skin in YouTube (through Video.js) but not sure if i can do the same for vimeo and dailymotion as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used them, but there are also video.js plugins for playing back Vimeo and Dailymotion in the same way as you've done for You Tube. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to customize the look of the player outside the embed settings provided on the video's settings page.

PRO members can get urls for their video files that they can use in whatever player they want.